# How can I create a generic model for EntityManager?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying create something using ZF2 and Doctrine 2. But I'm kind lost about what I want to achieve.

First I now that using `$em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');` inside controller it will work.

But what I want it's something more elaborated, like this:

```
class BaseModel extends Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
{
  public function save()
  {
    $em->persist($this);
    $em->flush();
  }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Customer extends BaseModel
{
  // getters setters
}

class IndexController
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
    $customer = new Customer();
    $customer->setName('asd');
    $customer->save();

    Customer::findAll();
  }
}
```

I have started this:

```
namespace Ws\Model;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

class BaseModel implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
  use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

  public function write() {
        $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
        return $em->getRepository(__CLASS__);
    }
}
```

But without success.

I understand that this is more than one question, but is it possible help me here even passing some links that could help me in this journey?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want an active record implementation then use an active record based orm such as propel or eloquent.  I'm sure zf has a way to hook it in.  Trying to use a data mapper such as Doctrine will cause endless frustration.  How about using Doctrine the way it was designed?  Might be surprised at it's power.   There are reasons why it is by far the most popular orm out there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait` implemntation ? It just give you [the getter and setter](https://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.4/classes/Zend.ServiceManager.ServiceLocatorAwareTrait.html), but of course, if you never set it, you will never get it. So `$this->getServiceLocator()` will always return null.

You'd better use dependency injection (never inject service locator but the needed services) or maybe, as pointed by @Cerad, use Doctrine the way it was designed.

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck. Just created that myself to use in my own vendor package.

You're code is messy though, I'm going to assume that the "Model" your refer to is the `Entity` and not a combination of `Entity` and `Repository`.

However, to the code!

Make special note of the namespaces and **organize folder structure and file names accordingly**!

File: repoName/src/Entity/AbstractEntity.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\Core;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Company\Core\Listener\ServiceLocatorAwareEntity;

/**
 * Class AbstractEntity
 * @package Company\Core\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
abstract class AbstractEntity extends ServiceLocatorAwareEntity
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return AbstractEntity
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

File: repoName/src/Service/AbstractEntityService.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\Core\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Company\Core\Interfaces\EntityServiceInterface;

abstract class AbstractEntityService implements EntityServiceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $entityManager;

    /**
     * AbstractEntityService constructor.
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return EntityManager
     */
    public function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
     */
    public function getEntityRepository()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository(__CLASS__);
    }

    //Feel free to add more functions here that you want all of your Entities to have
}
```

File: repoName/src/Interfaces/EntityServiceInterface.php (note, plural "interfaces" folder, as "interface" is protected name in PHP)

```
<?php

namespace Company\Core\Interfaces;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Repository\RepositoryFactory;

interface EntityServiceInterface
{
    /**
     * @return EntityManager
     */
    public function getEntityManager();

    /**
     * @return RepositoryFactory
     */
    public function getEntityRepository();

    //Feel free to add more functions here
}
```

File: repoName/src/Listener/ServiceLocatorAwareEntity.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Core\Listener;

use Zend\Di\ServiceLocator;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class ServiceLocatorAwareEntity implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    protected $sm;

    /**
     * Set the service locator
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $sm
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $sm)
    {
        $this->sm = $sm;
    }

    /**
     * Get the service locator
     *
     * @return ServiceLocator ServiceLocator instance
     */
    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->sm;
    }
}
```

In the Module.php file add following `onBootstrap()` function

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    /** @var EntityManager $em */
    $em = $sm->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');

    /** @var \Doctrine\Common\EventManager $dem */
    $dem = $em->getEventManager();
    /**
     * Binds adding EventListener "ServiceManagerListener" to the Doctrine Event PostLoad
     */
    $dem->addEventListener([Events::postLoad], new ServiceManagerListener($sm));
}
```

Because of this setup, make sure to had the `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks` Doctrine Annotation to the Entity class. The above function triggers the adding of the `ServiceManagerListener`, which in turn triggers the remainder.

Now all that remains is using it in your own modules (repeat endlessly if needed :) ).

#### Here we go back to the application itself.

Make sure you do the below for each of your entities and controllers and you should be fine.

Create the following:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Service;

use Company\Core\Service\AbstractEntityService;

class IndexControllerService extends AbstractEntityService
{
    //Yes really, this class is empty. Extends an Abstract class which may not be directly instantiated.
}
```

Create a factory for you IndexController

```
<?php

namespace Application\Factory;

use Application\Controller\IndexController;
use Application\Service\IndexControllerService;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;

class IndexControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface|ControllerManager $serviceLocator
     * @return IndexController
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        /** @var ServiceManager $serviceManager */
        $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        /** @var EntityManager $entityManager */
        $entityManager = $serviceManager->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        /** @var IndexControllerService $entityService */
        $entityService = new IndexControllerService($entityManager);
        /** @var IndexController $controller */
        $controller = new IndexController($entityService);

        return $controller;
    }
}
```

Make sure that your IndexController extends the AbstractActionController

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Company\Core\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

And make sure that you've registered this configuration in the config files using the following:

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        IndexController::class => IndexControllerFactory::class,
    ],
],
'service_manager' => [
    'invokables' => [
        IndexControllerService::class => IndexControllerService::class,
    ],
],
```

There ya go, should be all set.